# Is there an alternative to Arc<> wrapping for long-running threads which share data?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have some `threads`, which are long running, they are fed by a `Deque`, which has data pushed into it by another long running `thread`. Currently, I'm using `std::thread::spawn`, and have to wrap the `Deque` in an `Arc<>` to share it between the threads. If I use `&deque`, I run into the classic `'static lifetime` issue, hence the `Arc<>`. I've looked at scoped threads, however, the closure which the threads run it won't return for a very long time, so I don't think that will work for this case. Is anyone aware of an alternative solution -- short of using `Unsafe`? I'm not satisfied with the `Arc<>` solution. Each time I touch the `Deque` the code digs into `Arc<>'s` inner to get to the `Deque`, incurring overhead which I'd like to avoid. I've also considered making the `Deque` `static`, however it would need to be a `lazy static` due to the allocation restriction on `static`, and that comes with its own access overhead.

Comment: Have you measured the overhead? Accessing  the inner of an Arc is a single pointer de-reference, which should be vastly cheaper than whatever you are doing in each thread.

Comment: Why do you care that the closure won't return for a very long time? Scoped threads just provide a means for proving to the compiler that your threads are joined while the captured references are still valid. There is no requirement for the closures to finish in a short time period, or in any partticular time period whatsoever. If your code using scoped threads compiles, it will work just fine.

Comment: Regarding scoped threads. Unless I misunderstood the pattern, the caller of the closure won't regain control until the thread ends. I'm working in a server model where the caller of the closure needs to regain control while the threads continue executing. Later, they'd be told to shutdown and joined.

Comment: That's different from what you wrote in the question, but yes, you understood it correctly and if that's the case, you'll need to use `Arc`. Note that `Arc` doesn't necessarily carry an overhead wherever you use it - for example, you could [convert it to reference](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f8ab8c65fcd72396688deac9fd753be6) at the beginning of the thread and pass it around as reference instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a `&Dequq` out of the `Arc<Deque>` just once  at the beginning of your long-running thread and keep using that immutable reference throughout its life.  Something like this:

```
let dq: Arc<Deque<T>> = ....;
....
{
    let dq2 = Arc::clone(dq);
    thread.spawn(move || {
        let dq_ref: &Deque<T> = *dq2;
        // long-running calculation using dq_ref
        // dq2 is dropped
   });
}
```

Comment: Chances are excellent the compiler already does this in all non-perverse cases.